# PHP вопрос про sleep

Tags: php

Во время "сна", скрипт нагружает ресурсы, или это тоже самое что он не работает, или нагрузка есть, но не существенна, по сравнению с выполнением скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока процесс находится в "спящем" режиме он не будет потреблять ресурсы, но сам рабочий процесс продолжается и для этого нужна физическая память или файл подкачки. То есть процесс интерпретации PHP должен продолжать работать.

Это я к чему, необходимо понимать для чего вы останавливаете процесс, чтобы выполнить что-то другое? Допустим если процесс будет в спящем режиме и вы заберете 100% остаток ресурсов на что-нибудь другое, то PHP процесс может упасть.

Также стоит отметить, что если вы долго будете спать, то сервер/хостинг может убить ваш процесс (зависит от настроек).

Answer (score 3):

При команде `sleep`:

- ресурсы CPU не используются
- оперативная память занята на протяжении всего сна ровно на столько, на сколько была занята в момент вызова sleep